# Matching password in .Net validate by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-membership, .net-2.0

I have two textbox in Asp.Net: first for password and second is for a matching password.

How can I validate whether user entered different value in both textboxes through JavaScript at client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest js for this would be

```
if(document.getElementById('password1').value != document.getElementById('password2').value){
    // they do not match
}
```

But if you are using .NET, you might want to take the advice to use a CompareValidator.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) control for this?

It's what the CompareValidator was designed for.

**edit - added**

If you just want the javascript and want to do it completely in javascript, here's an example:

http://www.willmaster.com/library/manage-forms/ensuring-two-form-fields-have-identical-information.php

However, the CompareValidator takes care of generating the javascript for you (as long as client side validation is turned on), so in my opinion (and it IS just an opinion) you're making it harder on yourself by writing the javascript yourself.

Comment: bingo! Could also consider using the `ChangePassword` control

Comment: want javascript for validate them